# Highlight selected text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

When a user selects any text in my html page I want to add a custom style (like `color:red;`) to it. This will act as a highlighting tool similar to what you can see in some applications for reading pdf files.

To do this I declare `highlight()` function that gets the text which is selected, plus its position.

```
function highlight(text, x, y) {
        alert(text+'***'+x+'***'+y)
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
```

jsfiddle link edited

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/7xpJH/)

Comment: Try the [Rangy](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/core.html) plugin - it offers exactly what you need, with complete cross browser support.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach instead.  Basic steps are get your selection, pass it into the getRangeAt method and then create a new span element to surround the selection and apply your class attribute.

```
$(document).on("mouseup", function (e) {
    var selected = getSelection();
    var range = selected.getRangeAt(0);
    if(selected.toString().length > 1){
        var newNode = document.createElement("span");
        newNode.setAttribute("class", "red");
        range.surroundContents(newNode);       
    }
    selected.removeAllRanges();
 });

function getSelection() {
    var seltxt = '';
     if (window.getSelection) { 
         seltxt = window.getSelection(); 
     } else if (document.getSelection) { 
         seltxt = document.getSelection(); 
     } else if (document.selection) { 
         seltxt = document.selection.createRange().text; 
     }
    else return;
    return seltxt;
}
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/bZb7V/)**

Comment: +1 Any suggestions to make it work if you select text from different `div` elements? Because it doesn't work if you do so...

Comment: @jme11 thanks,but how can give this choose to user that select what style is applied..?

Comment: i found a problem, if area selection contain either `<h2>` element and `<div>` element or etc the style is declared don't applied...

Comment: There's quite a lot more that would have to go into writing something that would allow for this to work across multiple block level elements.  If you need this functionality, then I recommend this plugin: http://mir3z.github.io/jquery.texthighlighter/ It's the only one I've come across that handles this scenario.  Better yet, it has methods for setting the color of the highlight.

Answer (score 2):

After some research i suggest to go this way.

**html**

```
<h3 class="foo">hello world! hello world! hello world</h3>
<div class="foo">hello world! hello world hello world!</div>
<span class="foo">hello world! hello world</span>
```

**css**

```
.foo::selection {
    color:#ff0099;
}

.bar::selection {
    color: red;   
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".foo").removeClass("foo").addClass("bar");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xpJH/21/)

First add a `class` in your element you want to use the effect. After use [selection](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp) selector and with `js` `add` and `remove` the `classes`. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @KristianBarrett that's what OP asked for, is it not? As elegant as this solution is, if you need support for < IE9, this won't work. +1 regardless.

Comment: Yes but this will not stick and only color the selection. I might have misunderstood what he was asking but I thought it was a highlight mechanism to highlight parts of the text you just read.

Comment: @alek i want when user selected any text, i show popup that user can choose what style is applied.

Comment: @user3760964 You will need to use the Rangy plugin I mentioned in my comment on your question then.