# How to wrap the selected text in to `span` element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to wrap the `selected` in to `span` element. how can i do that? any one help me to solve this please?

```js
function getSelectionParentElement() {
    var parentEl = null, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            parentEl = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
            if (parentEl.nodeType != 1) {
                parentEl = parentEl.parentNode;
                console.log("i done", sel.toString()); //i am getting string.
              //this string should wrap in to span element with .highlight class added.
            }
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        parentEl = sel.createRange().parentElement();
    }
    return parentEl;
}

$('p').on('mouseup', function () {
    var textParent = getSelectionParentElement();
});
```

```css
.highlight{
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

i am working for both modern browsers and `ie9`.

```
result expecting: '<span class="highlight">selected text here </span>'
```

Comment: Check this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342007/highlight-selected-text-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

This is a start, although not the most beautiful code in the world. This will keep the highlighted bits highlighted though, but I guess you can add code to clear this yourself.

```js
function getSelectionParentElement() {
  var parentEl = null,
      sel;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      parentEl = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
      if (parentEl.nodeType != 1) {
        parentEl = parentEl.parentNode;
        console.log("i done", sel.toString()); //i am getting string.
        //this string should wrap in to span element with .highlight class added.
        return sel.toString();
      }
    }
  } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    parentEl = sel.createRange().parentElement();
  }
  return parentEl;
}

$('p').on('mouseup', function() {
  var textParent = getSelectionParentElement();
  if (textParent.length > 3) {
     var fulltxt = $('p').html();
     var regex = new RegExp(textParent, "g");
     $('p').html(fulltxt.replace(regex,'<span class="highlight">'+textParent+'</span>'));
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
       background: yellow;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

Comment: Not working with selecting multiple elements to gather: http://jsfiddle.net/2jsz15de/1/

Comment: Added a "if (textParent.length > 3)", since it crashed my browser when I tried unselecting ;-)

Comment: Then I don't know what result you are looking for. The code I posted works like I interpret your question. Do you want to selected text to be shown in it's own paragraph? like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2jsz15de/3/

Comment: Instead of selecting text, start from top (title) and end with last line. nothing selected.