# Add a Bullet Point to <p> when highlighted dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Update:** Example: `<p contenteditable="true">Text Text </p>`
Is it possible, within the example, to select the second "text" word within the `<p>` element and click the button to add a bullet point only to the selected "word" dynamically?

---

Is it possible, within a `<p contenteditable="true">Text</p>` to highlight selected text from the `<p>` element and add a bullet point to the selected text on a button click dynamically?

If an updated fiddle could be provided, it would be very much appreciated, as I am still new to coding.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srj26gw1/1/)

HTML:

```html
<button>
Apply Bullet Point to Selected Text
</button>

<p contenteditable="true">
Text
Text
</p>

<br>

<p contenteditable="true">
Text
Text
</p>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/srj26gw1/2/

Comment: However, this code adds the bullet point to all <p> elements and not the selected text.

Comment: Understood your `Text` is separated by newlines. If the second `Text` is selected, do you want to apply a bullet point to the entire text (e.g. `• Text\nText`) or `Text\n• Text`?

Comment: For example: `<p contenteditable="true">Text Text </p>`                                  Is it possible to select the second "text" and click the button to add a bullet point only to the selected text dynamically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it the following way using jQuery:

```js
function getText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode;
    } 
    return '';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnClick').click(function () {
        getText().innerHTML = "\u2022" + getText().innerHTML;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnClick">
Apply Bullet Point to Selected Text
</button>

<p id="text1" contenteditable="true">
Text
Text
</p>

<br>

<p id="text2" contenteditable="true">
Text
Text
</p>
```

**[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/srj26gw1/3/)**

---

If you want to replace the selected text with a bullet then do the following:

```
getText().anchorNode.parentNode.innerHTML = "\u2022" + getText();
```

Otherwise if you want to append/edit the text, then you want to put more effort into it:

**[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/srj26gw1/9/)**

**Updated:**

At the end get the result:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnClick').click(function () {

    var selected = getText();
    if (selected.toString().length > 0) {
      if ($(selected.anchorNode.parentNode).attr('contenteditable')) {
        var bulletText = document.createTextNode(" \u2022 " + getText() );
        selected.getRangeAt(0).surroundContents(bulletText);
      }
    }
    });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srj26gw1/13/)**

Comment: However, this code adds the bullet point to the entire <p> element and not the selected text.

Comment: Thank you! This code works perfectly. Also, is it possible to add a remove bullet point button?

Comment: @Dave for that need to do some efforts. Let me check if i can do. required some time

Answer (score 9):

Yes. It is possible. Using a similar example from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342007/highlight-selected-text-with-jquery/24342137#24342137), you can consider using the following JS. The logic is to wrap the selected text with `<li>` element.

```
$('button').on("click", function(e) {
  var selected = getSelection();
  var range = selected.getRangeAt(0);
  if (selected.toString().length > 0) {
    // Check if parent element has contenteditable attr set to true.
    if ($(selected.anchorNode.parentNode).attr('contenteditable')) {
      var newNode = document.createElement("li");
      range.surroundContents(newNode);
    }
  }
  selected.removeAllRanges();
});

function getSelectedText() {
  var selectedText = '';
  if (window.getSelection) {

    selectedText = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.getSelection) {
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    // For IE prior to 9 as it does not support document.getSelection().
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
  } else return;
  return selectedText;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srj26gw1/6/) for a working example.

---

**Edit**

I've also updated the code such that elements without `contenteditable` set to `true` won't have the `<li>` element wrapped.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srj26gw1/12/) and code (see above). This should be what you want.

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors when you put it in your codes?

Comment: I have tried using the <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> function. However, the code does not work, only in JSFiddle.

Comment: You have to add as `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` (note the `https://` protocol).

Comment: I have tried the solution above, however, the code is still not working. It only works in JSFiddle.

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors? Check your console in developer tools (press `F12` on your keyboard).

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded  -  function getSelection() {

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery plugin.

```js
$(function(){
         $('button').on('click', function(){
          $('p').css({'display': 'list-item', 'margin-left':'25px'});
          
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Apply Bullet Point to Selected Text
</button>

<p contenteditable="true">
Text
Text
</p>

<br>

<p contenteditable="true">
Text
Text
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the simple solution will work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   var lstEl;
  
  $("p").on('focus', function () {
       lstEl = $(this);
  });
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    if(!lstEl.hasClass("bult")){
      lstEl.addClass('bult')
      }
  })
})
```

```css
.bult{
     list-style:disc outside none;
     display:list-item; 
  margin-left:10px
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Apply Bullet Point to Selected Text
</button>

<p contenteditable="true">
Text
Text
</p>

<br>

<p contenteditable="true">
Text
Text
</p>
```

Comment: However, this code adds the bullet point to the entire <p> element and not the selected element. For example, is it possible to double click one of the words within the <p> element and then click the button to add the bullet point only to the selected word?