# How to change css property of the particular selection text in a input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is my sample demo:

```
<span style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">CHANGE</span>
<form>
    <textarea >hello, world</textarea/>
</form>
```

I want to change the selected text color( selected text will be dynamic) an input field. Color change can be according to:

he : red color(if he selected) 
hello : blue (if hello selected), so on.
selected color will be changed after click CHANGE text.

Comment: How about `contenteditable='true'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a textarea. Any text-related property will affect the whole text within the the textarea.

Following way you can change the color of text dynamically for p element.

Use `contenteditable="true"` to your `p` tag

```js
function getText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) { 
         return document.selection.createRange().text; 
     }
    return '';
}

document.getElementById('btnClick').addEventListener('click', function() 
{
  if(getText() == "hello")
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "#ff0000") 
  else
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "#0000ff") 
        
});
```

```html
<button id="btnClick">Change Color</button>

<p id="text1" contenteditable="true">hello, world</p>
```

This way you can check if text is hello then will change that selected text to red. Else for another text change it to blue.

You can change the condition as per your requirement.

Check my [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327441/add-a-bullet-point-to-p-when-highlighted-dynamically/34327677#34327677) for more details.

Comment: @RayonDabre Yeah. OP can change the condition as per their requirement. Main thing is to change the color as per text.

Comment: Wow, awesome, I have got my main think. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `contenteditable='true'` instead of `textarea`

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('handler').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('red').classList.add('red');
  document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('blue');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;" id='handler'>CHANGE</span>
<form>
  <div contenteditable='true'>
    <span id='red'>hello, </span>
    <span id='blue'>world</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just add an `onclick` to each span and you're set.

Comment: I want to change color on specific select text, Here CHANGE text will be color input field.

Comment: _specific select text_ ? What do you mean by that ?

Comment: (1). When I will select just hello text then color will be changed. (2).Again when I will select another text in the text area then color will be changed. Actually I want to edit text area value like as HTML editor.

Comment: Answering question can be replaced by: <input type="color" />
<form>
 <textarea >many text here</textarea/>
</form>

Comment: Why on earth would you get him to make things more difficult for himself by using a contenteditable div instead of textarea?

Comment: @MatthewLymer, Because there is no way you can apply different CSS to different words in a textarea....

Comment: I don't want apply different css to different words. I want different css to different select word in a textarea.

Comment: @AbdusSalam I don't understand your last question - you basically said you don't want to apply css to different words, but to different select words - what do you mean? Sounds like the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

update your html as suggested by @rayon Dabre

HTML

```
<span style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;" id='handler'>CHANGE</span>
<div contenteditable='true'>
    <span id='txt'>hello, world</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('txt').addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    var selection = (window.getSelection) ? window.getSelection().toString() : document.selection.createRange().text;
    this.textContent = this.textContent; //remove child tags before wrap
    wrapWithTag(this, selection ? selection : "");
}, false);
var textAndColor = {//Object to update color as per selected text
    "he": "red",
    "hello": "blue",
    "world": "yellow"
};
function wrapWithTag(stringElement, txtToWrap) {
    if(!txtToWrap) {return;}
    var originalTxt = stringElement.textContent;
    var beforeString = originalTxt.substring(originalTxt.indexOf(txtToWrap), 0);
    var AfterString = originalTxt.substring(originalTxt.indexOf(txtToWrap) + txtToWrap.length);
    if(textAndColor[txtToWrap]) {
        stringElement.innerHTML = beforeString + "<span id='highlight' class=' "+ textAndColor[txtToWrap] +"'>" + txtToWrap + "</span>" + AfterString;
    }
}
document.getElementById('handler').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var textContainer = document.getElementById('highlight');
    if(textContainer) {
        textContainer.style.color = textContainer.className;
    }
}, false);
```